# Excel: Using lookup or match to find things in ascending order

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, the functions `lookup` and `match` are for descending order.

Are there functions like these which work for ascending order?

Comment: Match does ascending and descending, as well as exact match for unsorted lists.  Look in help for the details.

Answer (score 0):

While lookup works for ordered lists only, `MATCH` does not need this if the `match_type` (3rd arg) is set to zero.

```
= MATCH(value, list, 0)
```

Comment: waht you mean???